# What's better for a WPF game-using a grid or a canvas?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, canvas, grid

I want to make a game using WPF and I'm not sure what should I use, a grid or a canvas? I know that in a grid everything gets changed once I change the window size mid run, I don't know if I can bypass that and maybe I would even want to make a full screen option, nevertheless, it's not an adventure game just something like Tom The Talking Cat,where you take care of a character and buy things for it. What do you think I should use?(p.s I'm sorry that my English is bad and I'm kind of new in programming so I might sound a bit ignorant but I'm trying to learn to get better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any layout which can be done with Canvas, can also be done with Grid.

E.g. take a Canvas, a Grid with single RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition, and some UIElement (Border). The Border can be positioned in Canvas using Top and Left properties, and in the same location of Grid using Margin property:

```
<Canvas>
  <Border Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="10" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Purple"/>
</Canvas>

<Grid>
  <Border Margin="20,10,0,0" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Purple"/>
</Grid>
```

To have more advanced functionality you can even implement your own type of Panel:

```
public class BraveNewPanel: Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
         // measure children
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
         // arrange children
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas, then you have complete control over everything. If you look at Grid it can interfere with things.

Comment: Any layout which can be done with Canvas, can also be done with Grid. Please share what exactly is not under complete control of developer. Also Grid doesn't interfere with anything, there just may be people using it wrong

Comment: Complete control like putting UI elements where no-one can see or use them. Fixed layouts are the number 1 cause of poor UX if not complete defunct UIs. It's not the 90s anymore, don't dig up Canvas from its grave unless you are doing embedded programming for a specific piece of hardware.